# Push notifications not work in IOS IONIC 4 cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, apple-push-notifications, cordova-ios

I’m using Ionic 4 and ANGULAR version 9 trying to send notification in IOS using Cordova.

I did all the requirements to push IOS notification and it was working fine before that but I’m not sure what happened if some packages version not match or whatever.

**Here is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tagy",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-fetch": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "1.2.5",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "6.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "0.7.3",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "2.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "1.3.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.7.1",
    "ngx-qrcode2": "^9.0.0",
    "npm": "^7.21.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Here is app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// FCM
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    FCM,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**Here is app.component.ts code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Platform, NavController, ToastController, AlertController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { ProvidersService } from './providers.service';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
import { Badge } from '@ionic-native/badge/ngx';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';

declare var Puship;

/*
interface Window {
    FirebasePlugin: any;
}*/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
     public selectedIndex = 0;
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/tabs',
      icon: 'home'
    },

    /*
    {
      title: 'Loyalty Points',
     // url: '/point',
      icon: 'ribbon'
    },

    */

     {
      title: 'Appointment',
      url: '/tabs/tab1/appointment',
      icon: 'ribbon'
    },



    {
      title: 'Loyalty e-Voucher',
      url: '/tabs/tab1/voucher',
      icon: 'cash'
    },


    {
      title: 'My Favorites Merchants',
      url: '/tabs/tab1/favourite',
      icon: 'heart'
    },
    {
      title: 'My Vehicle',
      url: '/update-vehicle',
      icon: 'cog'
    },
    {
      title: 'Profile & Settings',
      url: '/update-profile',
      icon: 'settings'
    },
    {
      title: 'Gallery',
      url: '/gallery',
      icon: 'image'
    },
    {
      title: 'Qr code',
      url: '/tabs/tab1/qrcode',
      icon: 'apps'
    },
    {
      title: 'Invite Friends',
      url: '/tabs',
      icon: 'people-circle',
      fn: () => this.share()
    },
    {
      title: 'About App',
      url: '/about',
      icon: 'information-circle'
    },
    {
      title: 'Help',
      url: '/help',
      icon: 'help-buoy'
    },
    {
      title: 'Deactivate Account',
      url: '/delete',
      icon: 'person-circle',
     fn: () => this.cancel()
    }
  ];
  pic:any;
  name:any;
  phone:any;
  code:any;
  data:any;
  items:any;
  data1:any;
  data2:any;
  auth2:any;
  items1:any;
  data3: any;
  items3: any;
  exist3: any;
  notiunread:any;
  point:any;
  userData={
        "token":"",
        "id":"",
        "plid":""
  };

  constructor(
      private router: Router,
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
      private providersservices: ProvidersService ,
      private toastctrl: ToastController,
      public navctrl: NavController,
      private menuCtrl: MenuController,
      private alertCtrl: AlertController,
      private socialSharing: SocialSharing,
    private badge: Badge,
    private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
    private fcm: FCM,
    private push: Push
  )


    
  {
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.badge.set(this.notiunread);

    this.initializeApp();
  }

  


  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
        if(SigninData!=null){
            console.log("have data");
            this.router.navigate(["/tabs"], { skipLocationChange: true });
        } else {
            console.log("no data");
            this.router.navigate(["/landing"], { skipLocationChange: true });
        }



    //  this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
        console.log(token);
      }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

      // ionic push notification example
      this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.wasTapped) {
          console.log('Received in background');
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab1/notification']);
        } else {
          this.backgroundMode.enable();
          this.badge.set(this.notiunread);
          console.log('Received in foreground');
          this.call(data);
        }
      });

      // refresh the FCM token
      this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        console.log(token);
      }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });



    });

    this.providersservices.getObservable().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('Data received', data);
        this.pic = data.pic;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.phone = data.number;
    });

    const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
    if(SigninData!=null){
        const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
        this.userData.id=SigninData.mem_id;
        this.userData.token=SigninData.token;
        this.userData.plid = "7";
        this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "memberencrypt").subscribe((result) =>{
            this.data = result;
            this.items = this.data.data;
            this.code = this.items.mem_id;
            console.log(result);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }


 this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "badgenotification").subscribe((result) =>{
    this.data3 = result;
    this.items3 = this.data3.data;
    this.notiunread = this.items3.length;
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
      console.log(this.notiunread);
    this.badge.set(this.notiunread);

    if(Array.isArray(this.items3))
      this.exist3 = this.items3[0].exist;
    else
      this.exist3 = this.items3.exist;
    console.log(result);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  });


    this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "pointshare").subscribe((result) =>{
        this.data1 = result;
        this.items1 = this.data1.data;
        this.point = this.items1.pl_value;
        console.log(result);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });

    if(this.pic==undefined&&this.name==undefined&&this.name==undefined){
        const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
        if(SigninData!=null){
            this.pic = SigninData.mem_photo;
            this.name = SigninData.mem_name;
            this.phone = SigninData.mem_phonetcode + SigninData.mem_phone;
        }
    }
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'custom');



{
    //this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'ml']);
    //this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
 }

  }


    switchLang(lang: string)
  {
  //  this.translate.use(lang);
  }

  async call(id:any){
        const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
          subHeader: id.title,
          message: id.body,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Open Notification",
              handler: () => {
                 this.router.navigate(['/notification']);
              }
            },
            {
              text: "Later",
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        await alert.present();
    }

    updateprofile(){
        this.router.navigate(['/update-profile']);
    }


    logout(){

        const RememberData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rememberme"));

        if(RememberData!=null){
          if(RememberData.rmbme=="false"){
            console.log("rmbme false");
            localStorage.removeItem("signindata");
            this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'custom');
            this.navctrl.navigateRoot(['/login']);
          }else{
            localStorage.removeItem("signindata");
            this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'custom');
            this.navctrl.navigateRoot(['/login']);
          }
          console.log("rmbme true");
        } else {
            console.log("null");
            localStorage.removeItem("signindata");
            this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'custom');
            this.navctrl.navigateRoot(['/login']);
        }

        this.presentToast("Logout Successfully");
    }

    async share() {
      const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
           subHeader: 'Invite Friends',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'ANDROID',
                handler: () => {
                  this.shareandroid();
                }
              }, {
                text: 'IOS',
                handler: () => {
                 this.shareios();
                }
              }
            ]
        });
        await alert.present();
    }



    shareandroid() {
        this.socialSharing.share("").then(() => {
          console.log("Share: Success");
        }).catch(() => {

          console.error("Share: failed");
        });
    }

    shareios() {

         alert("In Progress");
    }

    async presentToast(a){
        const toast = await this.toastctrl.create({
            message: a,
            duration: 1500
        });
        toast.present();
    }


    async cancel(){

       const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: 'Deactivate Account',
          message: 'Cancel will delete your account. Continue?',
           buttons: [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
              }
            }, {
              text: "Yes",
              handler: () => {
               this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "deleteaccount").subscribe((result) => {
                    this.data2 = result;
                    this.auth2 = this.data2.result;
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log(this.auth2);

                    if(this.auth2.auth=="success"){
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);

                    }
                }, (err) => {
                    this.presentToast("Please connect your device to internet!");
                });
              }
            }
          ]
        });

        await alert.present();
    }

    
}
```

I’m using the same code with android, the notification badge working fine.
Could anyone help me check please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done solved this issue by upgrade xcode to version 13.4. The problem was because I was using old version of xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to grant permission before getToken(). The permission at Android is by default, but iOS - don`t.
For example:

```
try {
 const hasPermission = await this.firebase.hasPermission();
 if (!hasPermission) { permission = await this.firebase.grantPermission(); }
} catch (e) { console.log('FCM get permission error: ', e); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already solved my problem by upgrade xcode.